# Need help identifying circuit diagram symbol

Tags: identification, cmos, ttl

In the datasheet for Hamamatsu s13131-1536 CMOS line sensor(https://www.hamamatsu.com/content/dam/hamamatsu-photonics/sites/documents/99_SALES_LIBRARY/ssd/s13131-1536_kmpd1159e.pdf) there is this symbol in the application circuit diagram. Is it just CMOS-TTL buffer or is it something different? Why the dashed line is powered and grounded, do they mean that it is just part of one IC?
[image: Buffer like triangle enclosed in a dashed rectangular grounder contour]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is just a symbol for buffers.

For some reason they just drew two dual buffers, maybe because two are buffering signals in and two are buffering signals out, which means in your application you might need to have different kinds of buffers when interfacing with e.g. 5V MCU or 2.5V MCU.

Answer (score 1):

According to the datasheet, CLK, ST, EOS, and Trig all are digital signals.  To me, the schematic shows two separate ICs with separate power decoupling, each with two non-inverting digital buffers.

Note that the video signal buffer has an output impedance of 50 ohms, not 75 ohms as is common if video systems.